# How to customise Ethereum Network Status for a Private Network?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity

I am using this - https://github.com/cubedro/eth-netstats

I get this error -

> 2018-05-29 04:30:25.958 [API] WS_SECRET NOT SET!!!

I want to show the stats on a private parity PoA network.

Has anyone any suggestions about to configure Eth Netstats for this task? Also is this the main repo? I saw only only 484 stars.

Answer (score 0):

The answer -
1. use pm2 start app.json in the eth-net-intelligence-api one
2. use WS_SECRET=secret npm start in eth-netstats

Then it works.